# How to align growing textarea inline with buttons

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have a growing textarea aligned left, and action buttons to the right side of the textarea. I want to align the action buttons at the bottom at the same level with the growing text area.

Here's my markup:

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="mt-2">
          <textarea name="messages[]" @keyup="typing(index)" :id="'ta_'+index" v-model="messages[index]" class="form-control" rows="1" placeholder="Type a message"
          v-bind:class="{ 'is-invalid': errors.message }"
          ></textarea>
          <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert" v-if="errors.message">
              <strong>@{{errors.message}}</strong>
          </span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div :class="'text-right '">
      <div class="btn-actions mt-2">
          <button @click="setAction(index, conversation, 'sendOnly')" type="button" class="btn btn-default"
          :disabled="!messages[index]"
          >{{__('Send')}}</button>
          <button v-if="sendIndex !== index " @click="setAction(index, conversation, 'resolvedOnly')" type="button" class="btn btn-success">{{__('Mark as resolved')}}</button>
          <button v-if="sendIndex === index && messages[index] != ''" @click="setAction(index, conversation, 'sendResolved')" type="button" class="btn btn-success">{{__('Send + resolved')}}</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By the way, the question is tagged with [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js) to indicate what I'm using, but that has nothing to do with the problem. It's just a textarea and CSS matter.

And here's a screenshot that describes the scenario.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to the `btn-actions` class (i.e., [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) and [`align-items: flex-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)):

```css
.col {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 1em);
}

textarea {
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 1em;
}

.btn-actions {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div>
    <textarea rows="1" placeholder="Type a message"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="btn-actions">
      <button>Send</button>
      <button>Resolve</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```